# как можно упростить данный код

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Всем привет, написал код и хочу узнать можно ли как то его ещё сильнее у компановать?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;
#define N 4
#define M 4

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int i, j, d0,d=0;
    float W;
    int A[N][M], C[M], D[M];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cin >> A[i][j];

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cout << A[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            if(A[i][j] < 1)
            {
                cout << "Ошибка"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }

    cout << "\n";
    d0 = N * (M + 1) / 2;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        C[i] = 0;
        D[i] = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            C[i]+=A[i][j];
        }

        cout << C[i] << "\n";
        D[i] = pow((C[i] - d0),2);
        d += D[i];
    }

    cout << d << endl;
    W = (12*d) / (pow(N, 2) * (pow(M, 3) - M));
    cout << "W =" << W << endl;
    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: Что этот код делает? Можно как минимум убрать циклы с проверкой на -1.

Comment: Можно, конечно. Уберите все ваши матрицы и считайте нужные величины сразу при вводе. Слово "ошибка" тогда, правда, будет выведено посреди вывода ответов, но если так нельзя, то можно обойтись одним массивом для промежуточного хранения C[i].

Comment: @Zealint Можно, в общем то, просто создать boolean переменную, говорящую, были ли совершены ошибки.

Comment: Если вы напишите задачу, то можно будет оптимизировать. Считаете какой-то коэффициент, но вот какой?

Comment: @Miron , тогда будет нарушена логика программы, автору нужно чтобы слово "ошибка" вывелось ДО вывода чисел.

Comment: @Zealint да нет же, он сначала считывает, потом выводит считанное, затем выводит 'ошибку', если есть.

Comment: Вы сначала скажите, что код делать-то должен! потому что "компановать" надо начинать с понимания задачи. Разбираться в вашем неформатированном коде, как минимум, тяжело; как максимум - он может быть неверным...